# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' when trying to connect to cloudsql instance using python connector

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

## getconn now set to private IP

For below code, I am getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google' at line number 2, Can anyone pls tell what python package I have to install here.

```
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
import sqlalchemy

def getconn():
    conn = connector.connect(
      "instancename", # ::
      "pymysql",
      user="root",
      password="secret",
      db="mysql",
      ip_type=IPTypes.PRIVATE
    )
    return conn

# create connection pool
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "mysql+pymysql://",
    creator=getconn,
)

# connect to connection pool
with pool.connect() as db_conn:
    # query database and fetch results
    results = db_conn.execute("SHOW TABLES ")

    # show results
    for row in results:
        print(row)

# cleanup connector
connector.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not have installed the library:

```bash
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

python3 -m pip install cloud-sql-python-connector==0.9.3

python3 -m pip freeze | grep cloud
# cloud-sql-python-connector==0.9.3
```

See the library's documentation: [`cloud-sql-python-connector`](https://pypi.org/project/cloud-sql-python-connector/)